# SwiftUI or Swift library that mimics Apple's Onboarding style

Tags: swift, swiftui

im looking for a library that mimics Apple's own [onboarding screen](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/onboarding/) guide suggestions. 
[image]

I have seen third party apps do something similar, and maybe they are just manually doing it, but thought I'd ask if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Just H&H (head and hands). This can be done with any UI library.

Comment: Understood as I mentioned but just wanted to see if anyone has done a library specifically